# Handing a Deleted flag with BindingList<> in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, bindinglist

I have an application with a front end, and instead of deleting objects right away we have a flag on every object that says whether it is supposed to be deleted, so it can be handled later. So the problem is when I am using the object in front end with a DataGrid in WinForms. When I set the Deleted flag I would like the object to not be displayed in the DataGrid, with the BindingList<> as the DataSource of the DataGrid. Is there a way to force a filter every time the DataGrid is repainted? would this be a function of the DataGrid? Or a function of the BindingList<>? For those who are more visual here is a code example. (WARNING this is a code example for conceptual purposes)

test.cs

```
public class Person : INotifyProperyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    private bool _isForDelete;
    public bool IsForDelete
    {
        get { return _isForDelete; }
        set 
        {
            _isForDelete = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsForDelete")
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
     }
}
```

MyForm.cs

```
private BindingList<Person> _persons;

private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _persons = GetPersonsFromServer();
    //Obviously this doesn't work, but I can dream. This is the basic idea.
    _myDataGrid.DataSource = _persons.Where(x=>!x.IsForDelete);
}

private void DeleteBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(var row in _myDataGrid.SelectedRows)
    {
        var person = (Person)row.DataBoundItem;
        person.IsForDelete = true;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

One solution to your problem would be to loop through each row of the datagrid, get the object bound to it, check the property, and then if it is set to true suspend the binding, set the row to invisible and then resume the binding. Something like:

```
CurrencyManager cur = (CurrencyManager)datagrid.BindingContext[datagrid.Datasource];
cur.SuspendBinding();
datagridviewrow.Visible = false;
cur.ResumeBinding();
```